# Excel format data series keyboard shortcuts - don't seem to be working

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I am asking about keyboard shortcuts in Excel.

When you are editing a chart in Excel, the format task pane seems to have underlined keyboard shortcuts for various options. Mine don't seem to work, regardless if I try using the Alt key, etc.

How can I use the underlined letter shortcuts in the format chart task pane in excel?

For example, I have made a box and whisker plot in Excel, I want to quickly add a mean marker to my data series. When I right click on the data series I want to edit and select "Format Data Series", the task pane on the right has an option "Show **m**ean markers", with the "m" underlined. In my experience with Excel this should mean that there is an associated keyboard shortcut - however I am unable to activate it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you directly type the underline letter in your case type "m" to Show mean markers, instead of using Alt key.